# What is the name for the construction of this poset related to coherence of degeneracies of the simplex category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, simplicial-stuff, grothendieck-construction

I present you a family of posets here. I don't say the posets themselves have a conventional name. However I'm sure the general construction of this kind has received some terminology, related to Grothendieck construction, comma categories, category of elements, etc. I can't exactly nail it, so it would be very helpful if you could do it for me.

As usual, write $\Delta$ for the simplex category: the category of inhabited finite linearly ordered set and order-preserving sets. Let $\Delta_-$ and $\Delta_+$ denote the wide subcategory of degeneracy maps and face maps, respectively, of $\Delta$.

Let $\sigma$ be a simplex of the simplicial nerve $N(\Delta_-)$:
$$
\sigma\colon [n_0]\twoheadrightarrow [n_1]
 \twoheadrightarrow \dotsb \twoheadrightarrow [n_k],
$$
where each $\twoheadrightarrow$ lies in $\Delta_-$.
I would like to define a poset $P(\sigma)$ as:
$$
P(\sigma) := \left\{ \tau \overset{d}{\rightarrowtail} \tau' \overset{u}{\subset} \sigma \right\}.
$$
Before we define an order on this set, we need to clearify the meaning of the symbols here. Firstly $\tau' \overset{u}{\subset} \sigma$ denotes a face $\tau'$ of $\sigma$ in the nerve $N(\Delta_-)$. It is determined by a face map $u\colon [l] \rightarrowtail [k]$ in $\Delta_+$, and we have
$$
\tau' = u^*(\sigma)\colon [n_{u(0)}]\twoheadrightarrow [n_{u(1)}]
 \twoheadrightarrow \dotsb \twoheadrightarrow [n_{u(l)}].
$$
Secondly, $\tau \overset{d}{\rightarrowtail} \tau'$ denotes the vertex-wise family of face maps, i.e.
$$
\tau\colon [m_0]\twoheadrightarrow [m_1]
 \twoheadrightarrow \dotsb \twoheadrightarrow [m_l]
$$
is a diagram in $\Delta_-$ and $d_i\colon [m_i] \rightarrowtail [n_{u(i)}]$, for $i=0,1,\dotsc, l$, are face maps in $\Delta_+$ which, in $\Delta$, commutes all the squares.

We need to define an order on $P(\sigma)$. Given $\tau \overset{d}{\rightarrowtail} \tau' \overset{u}{\subset} \sigma$ and $\omega \overset{e}{\rightarrowtail} \omega' \overset{v}{\subset} \sigma$,
we say
$$
\left(\omega \overset{e}{\rightarrowtail} \omega' \overset{v}{\subset} \sigma\right) \le \left(\tau \overset{d}{\rightarrowtail} \tau' \overset{u}{\subset} \sigma\right),
$$
iff we have $\omega \overset{\exists f}{\rightarrowtail} \exists\omega'' \overset{\exists w}{\subset} \tau$ in the commutative way, i.e. $v=u\circ w$ in $\Delta_-$ and
$e_i = d_{w(i)}\circ f_i$.

I feel a strong déjà-vu looking at this, but I can't write it down into a conventional categorical construction. This clearly looks like a slice category, so if we can name the category with its objects simplices of the simplicial nerve $N(\Delta_-)$ and its morphisms $\bullet \rightarrowtail \bullet \subset \bullet$, we are done. However I can't go beyond that point, so your help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s one way to see it, if I’m not misunderstanding your definition.

- For a small category $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf{C}}\C$, take its *categorical nerve* $\newcommand{\N}{\mathbf{N}}\N\C$ to be the functor $\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}} \Delta^{\op} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ defined by $(\N\C)_k = \C^{[k]}$; and take its *semi-nerve* $\N_{+}\C$ to be the restriction of this to to $\Delta_{+}$.
- The Grothendieck construction $\int_{\Delta_{+}} \N_{+}\C$ is a split fibration over $\Delta_{+}$.  Its objects are strings $\sigma_0 \to \cdots \to \sigma_n$ in $\C$; its morphisms are $(\tau \overset{g}{\to} \tau' \overset{u}{\subseteq} \sigma)$, where $u$ is a face map and $\tau'$ is the restriction of $\sigma$ along $u$, and $g$ is a ladder in $\C$ from $\tau$ to $\tau'$.

Taking $\C := \Delta$, this is very nearly the category you describe in your last para (and so its slices are nearly the category you want overall), but it’s a bit more general: its objects are arbitrary strings in $\Delta$ (not just degeneracies) and its vertical maps are arbitrary ladders, not necessarily of face maps.

So we cut down to a subcategory.  This can be done already at the level of the functor $\N_{+}\C : \Delta_{+}^{\op} \to \mathbf{Cat}$, before taking the Grothendieck construction.  Suppose $\C$ has two distinguished wide subcategories of maps; call them $a$, $b$.  Then write $\N^{a,b}\C : \Delta^\op \to \mathbf{Cat}$ (and $\N_{+}^{a,b}$ similarly) for the functor where $(\N^{a,b}\C)_k$ is the subcategory of $\C^[k]$ whose objects are strings of $a$-maps, and whose arrows are ladders of $b$-maps.

Then $\int_{\Delta_{+}} \N_{+}^{-,+}\Delta$ is the category you describe in the last paragraph; and its slices are the posets you want overall.

In particular, $\Delta$ is playing two different roles here, which can be generalised separately:

- the *base* of the categorical semi-nerve, $\Delta_{+}$ along with its inclusion into $\mathbf{Cat}$;
- the *target* of the categorical semi-nerve, $\Delta$ with its two distinguished wide subcategories.

(This categorical (semi-)nerve is an instance of a well-established construction, the [generalised nerve/realisation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+and+realization); and the Grothendieck construction is of course very standard.  Cutting down to a subcategory of the nerve in this particular way is not something I’ve seen before.)